# Pymongo indexing with geosphere

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

Hello and thanks in advance for your time.I am new to MongoDB and Pymongo and  have the following code that provides me a type Error:"not enough arguments for format string" when i am trying indexing .

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
collection = connection.labdb.hotels

def execute_query(query):
    for doc in collection.find(query):
        print(doc)

execute_query(query1)

collection.create_index(["location",pymongo.GEOSPHERE])
points=[[-122, 35], [-120, 35], [-120, 38], [-122, 38], [-122, 35]]
within = {"$geoWithin":{"$geometry" : {"type" : "Polygon", coordinates: 
[[[]]]}}}
query2 = {"location": within}
execute_query(query2)
```

Script is running on 3.7 spyder editor and has been previously tested and succesfully worked on 2.7 Python Ver.Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a tuple inside the create_index list:

```
collection.create_index([("location",pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
```

and in the 'within' line you forgot marks in "coordinates" (also probably forgotthe points variable inside coordinates):

```
within = {"$geoWithin":{"$geometry" : {"type" : "Polygon", "coordinates": [points]}}}
```